# Unfortunately, you are not authorized to edit posts of this content type

Tags: wordpress, backend, edit, content-type

I wanted to know, why I can't edit my sites, posts & ACF fields, even though I am a admin?

Everytime there comes this error:  Unfortunately, you are not authorized to edit posts of this content type.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

There is the chance the WordPress install is corrupted or incomplete.
I'd consider a manual re-install of WordPress.
Download the core files from the WordPress website, go on to your FTP. Delete wp-admin and wp-includes folders, and replace with the folders you downloaded.